# Predecting age from weight and height, using neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network

Im new on machine learning and i was trying to write and alogrithim to predict the age of someone depending on his weight and height

Heres my data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# weight,height,age

data=[[50,160,15],
      [45,156,13],
      [55,162,17],
      [56,163,18],
      [58,163.4,20],
      [12,85,2],
      [14.2,95,3],
      [15.4,100,4],
      [32,138.4,10],
      [25.8,128.3,8]]

# missing age data
mys=[22.4,121.1]
```

taking random variables of the weights

```
w1=np.random.rand()
w2=np.random.rand()
b=np.random.rand()
```

to visualize the data

```
 for i in range(len(data)):
      point=data[i]
      plt.xlabel('weight')
      plt.ylabel('length')
    
    
      plt.scatter(point[0],point[1],c='red')
    plt.scatter(mys[0],mys[1],marker='x',color='black',s=80)
```

heres my neural network

```
alpha=0.00001


for i in range(500):
  ri=np.random.randint(len(data))
  point=data[ri]

  pred=(point[0]*w1)+(point[1]*w2)+b
  target=point[2]
  cost=(pred-target)**2


  dcost_pred=2*(pred-target)
  dpred_w1=point[1]
  dpred_w2=point[0]
  dpred_db=1

  dcost_w1=dcost_pred*dpred_w1
  dcost_w2=dcost_pred*dpred_w2
  dcost_b=dcost_pred*dpred_db

  w1=(w1-alpha*dcost_w1)
  w2=w2-alpha*dcost_w2
  b=b-alpha*dcost_b
  print(cost)
```

unfortunately my cost keeps increasing, i have two questions also
1-When should i use sigmoid ?
2-How to choose the correct alpha?

ps: im expecting 7 output (age of the missing data)

Comment: sigmoid is not the choice of activation for regression. Also, alpha is a hyperparameter which means it has to be tuned manually by you. you can consider increasing it logarithmically.

Comment: You code seems correct. I would suggest you to write it using class and methods for clarity. Also, make use of numpy in the process. pass batches in the network. It will work faster.

Comment: @ragnar im getting more confused, beacuase everything seems good

Comment: i tried taking alpha as a random number but that also didnt work

Comment: start alpha with higher value say alpha=1, then make it 0.1. Later decrease in fashion 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4 and so on.

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work !

Comment: I plotted the loss curve for the network it seems like there are periodic ups and downs. However, the overall trend is upwards. This makes me think that it might be a problem of properly tuning the network and not due to the structure.

Comment: Can you make use of momentum or learning rate scheduling ? and check whether it solves your problem?

Comment: im sorry im still in the early stages of learning ML, what is the momentum or learning rate scheduling?

Comment: They can modify the learning rate depending upon the loss. If the change in loss is small, then the change in weights and biases values after GD is also small and vice versa

Comment: with what should i compare my alpha ?

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three parts to the question you asked.

1st part (what's wrong with the code) Ans: There is nothing wrong as such. Just proper lr and initilization

2nd part(where to use sigmoid). Ans: Nowhere in regression.

3rd part(correct alpha): Ans: start with 1 run the model and observe loss. Make alpha=1e-1 and so on. In the entire process observe loss. Whichever alpha yields small loss, choose that.

Code for 1st part: (Make following chnages)

```
b=np.zeros((1,))
alpha=1e-5
```

Yeah, that's it :) You may keep a list of loss for each epoch loss. I kept it for your code and got following graph. (Note I used only 50 epochs. you may keep higher values)

[image: Loss Curve]

Full Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# weight,height,age

data=[[50,160,15],
      [45,156,13],
      [55,162,17],
      [56,163,18],
      [58,163.4,20],
      [12,85,2],
      [14.2,95,3],
      [15.4,100,4],
      [32,138.4,10],
      [25.8,128.3,8]]

# missing age data
mys=[22.4,121.1]

w1=np.random.rand()
w2=np.random.rand()
b=0
alpha=0.00001

loss = []
for i in range(50):
  ri=np.random.randint(len(data))
  point=data[ri]

  pred=(point[0]*w1)+(point[1]*w2)+b
  target=point[2]
  cost=(pred-target)**2


  dcost_pred=2*(pred-target)
  dpred_w1=point[1]
  dpred_w2=point[0]
  dpred_db=1

  dcost_w1=dcost_pred*dpred_w1
  dcost_w2=dcost_pred*dpred_w2
  dcost_b=dcost_pred*dpred_db

  w1=(w1-alpha*dcost_w1)
  w2=w2-alpha*dcost_w2
  b=b-alpha*dcost_b
  loss.append(cost)

plt.plot(loss)
```

Comment: Hope this answers all your questions. If this helped you then please upvote  as well as accept this answer :)

Comment: why should i make (b) an array?

Comment: also i tried the changes you made, but that didnt work also

Comment: If you don't want to do that then make it b=0.

Comment: I have modified the answer. Please check

Comment: done! , but in the future do i need to find the lr by trail and error ? or theres another way?

Comment: unfortunately, all the hyperparameters including lr has to be tuned the same way. better way is to plot the curves and observe the change w.r.t parameter you are tunning. btw on a side note, the answer has been accepted but not upvoted. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need of the sigmoid in linear regression as we want absolute values rather than probabilities.

For linear regression normal equation is better to use, for that you can refer to my github repo https://github.com/tunesh/Linear-Regression/blob/master/linear_regression.py

Comment: do you have any idea why the cost is increasing ?

Comment: you are updating the weights per instance(per data point) .....do it for a batch of data.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @TuneshVerma I don't agree with the second point. Acc. to Universal approximation theorem they can learn any function.

Comment: @Ezz If you write down the equations of the neural network you have designed  then, you will find that it is same as regression. So no need to drop this code and switch to regression code as both are equivalent.

Comment: @Ragnar, that was what i was thinking of, thanks for clarifying that